# Spark 2.2 Structured Streaming - duplicate check without watermark - controlling the duplicates state size

Tags: apache-spark, duplicates, spark-structured-streaming

We are implementing a real-time aggregation process with Spark 2.2 structured streaming. 
The windows calculated can be based on event time that comes as an attribute on the object being processed in the stream and also can be calculated according to the processing time of the system like was possible in previous versions.

In addition we need to implement duplicate check to prevent the processing of duplicate events.

In the documentation it is stated that

> **Without watermark** - Since there are no bounds on when a duplicate record may arrive, the query stores the data from all the past records as state. (https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/structured-streaming-programming-guide.html#streaming-deduplication)

The problem is that looks like this state can grow forever and cause performance and memory size issues. There seems to be no way in the API to control it

The question is is there a way to implement duplicate check on events that do not have a notion of event time and still maintain control on the duplicate check sate like clearing it etc.

Thanks!

Comment: *is there a way to implement duplicate check on events that do not have a notion of event time* You said that you are aggregating based on event time, but then you say you don't have event time. I'm not understanding the question.

Comment: We are using both event time aggregation and processing time aggregation. In case of event time there is no issue since we can use the watermark but in case of processing time this is not possible and will potentially create an ever growing duplicate check state.

Comment: You have to give Spark some upper limit to remove old state by, otherwise it'll eventually fail with out of memory.

Comment: Thanks for your answer!. this is exactly what I want to do just couldn't find how in the documentation. Can you explain how to do it in this case?